# Use parallel or series circuit for high power LED strip lights?

Tags: led-strip

I have a complex strip light installation and am working on the wiring plan. 5 watts per foot x 200 feet = 1000 watts at 24 volts DC which would be about 40 amps.

I have read web sites which give contradictory advice about how to wire LED strips. One web site said that they should be wired in series to guarantee that all LEDs are getting the same amperage. Another said that they should be wired in parallel so that they get the same voltage. Which advice is correct?

Note that I think the strips themselves are internally wired in series, so the question would only apply to the LED strips, not individual LEDs.

Comment: Due to the current limits on FPC Ledstrips they should be defined in specs e.g. 12/24/48V or 12 to 14.2V, 2 reels max in series, so any design must be based on the tolerances for current and voltage.

Typically simple white LEDs may be 3D+R for 12V strings and repeated in parallel so current depends on  voltage so each 5m reel could be an array of xSyP with current limiting R's chosen for rated voltage and current.

Comment: @TylerDurden It would be smart to post a schematic of what you are trying to do, including power sources! How long is the strip? This should influence your choice, because you will quickly see a large voltage drop on such small voltages as in the 12V range. Also, yes 40 amps is a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This entirely depends on what you call a "strip"... So make sure you know what you are ordering.

The most commonly available is the flexible LED strip. Here is an [example](https://www.lumitronix.com/en_gb/lumiflex700-economy-led-strip-warm-white-2700k-5m-24v-700-leds-3900lm-56046.html). You can also get them on metal-core PCBs.

[image]

Important things to notice are "24V DC" labeling, and presence of resistors. As is usually the case, white LEDs having an approximate Vf of 3-3.3V are wired as series groups of 3 LEDs for a 12V strip, or 6 LEDs for a 24V strip. Each group has its own resistor to set the current, and all groups are then wired in parallel. The strip can be cut between each group of LEDs.

These trade some efficiency for convenience. Resistors do waste some power, but you can simply wire the strips in parallel and use a constant voltage power supply.

There's a subtlety though: if you connect two strips together using the terminals at the end to make a longer strip, **they kind of look like they're wired "in series"** ... but they are not, this is parallel wiring since both + and - of one strip are connected to + and - of the next strip.

Note that copper traces on these are usually quite thin, so if you use a long high-power strip, drawing several amps, you might want to supply it from both ends or from the middle instead of at just one end, as voltage drop due to copper resistance can cause a drop in luminosity the further away you get from the supply connector. Likewise wiring several strips one after the other may cause drops in brightness. You can measure the voltage along the strip to make sure it's uniform.

Now there also "strips" which contain just LEDs and no resistors like [this one](https://www.lumitronix.com/en_gb/linearz-52-led-strip-zhaga-warm-white-3000k-2120lm-350ma-37-5v-52-leds-56cm-30102.html).

[image]

These also contain series-parallel groups of LEDs (or sometimes just one group) but no resistors. Presumably LEDs are binned by Vf to ensure adequate current sharing.

However, since these do not include resistors for higher efficieny, you must not use a constant voltage supply, rather use a constant current supply able to output the voltage that the LED module requires.

These can also be wired in parallel, but since there are no resistors, balanced current sharing is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Individual LED emitters can be wired in series, because they need constant current. You only need one current source per LED string.

LED strips do that for you.  You supply them constant voltage at 12/24V and they already have internal  series strings of 3 or 6 LEDs, with current regulation in each string. Every segment between cut lines is a series string, and each cuttable segment is then paralleled.    **This paralleling is built into the LED strip** if it has more than one unit segment.

It is possible to wire a multi-segment LED strip in series with another.  This had better be balanced,  though!  If you lose a segment,  you better rebalance it right away.  That said, I have had one such pair of strips  burning continuously for 6 years without incident.  So it WFM.

**Do not series stack them to high voltages**!!! LED strips are not insulated for that. And high voltage DC is one extremely rude customer. It's like a demonic version of AC. Look at 600V rated AC contactors and check their DC rating. Yeah.